# Node.hasChildNodes() returning reverse boolean values

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I had an xml document which I am trying to parse using DOM parser.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
    <trajectorys version="1.4.1.1">
    <trajectory uid="a" uidWell="b" uidWellbore="c">
       <nameWell>xval</nameWell>
       <nameWellbore>yval</nameWellbore>
       <trajectoryStation uid="0.00">
           <dTimStn>2017-02-04T10:51:20.000-06:00</dTimStn>
           <typeTrajStation>unknown</typeTrajStation>
       </trajectoryStation>
       <commonData>
           <dTimCreation>2017-02-20</dTimCreation>
           <dTimLastChange>2017-02-20</dTimLastChange>
       </commonData>
  </trajectory>
  </trajectorys>
```

I am trying to find child nodes using Node.hasChildNodes(). For *nameWell* and *nameWellbore* nodes, it is returning **True** even it has no child nodes while for *trajectoryStation* and *commonData* returns **False**.
I don't understand why this reverse behavior occurs for hasChildNodes method.

Answer (score 0):

All of the element nodes that you mention have child nodes, and the method returns true for all of them. Are you sure you're testing the correct nodes?

Note also that `#hasChildNodes()` includes all types of nodes, Element, Text, Comment, etc.

Update:

Just to give you an idea, this is how I usually gather child elements in DOM documents:

```
private List<Element> childElementsOf(Element parent) {
    List<Element> result = new LinkedList<>();
    Node node = parent.getFirstChild();
    while(node != null) {
        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            result.add((Element) node);
        }
        node = node.getNextSibling();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Ok.I don't know that *node* includes all elements,text etc..But I am sure that it is returning reverse values. My requirement is to check whether each element node has any child element node..If so, I need to iterate those child element nodes..  I mean child elements as tags.

Comment: It is getting same result after implementing your code. No change in output xml file

Comment: If you can share your code, we will be at a better position to help.

Comment: if (cNode.hasChildNodes()) {

                    NodeList cnode = cNode.getChildNodes();

                    for (int j = 0; j < cnode.getLength(); j++) {
                        Node cn = cnode.item(j);
                        if (cn.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                            -------
       other stuff
       --------
                        }
                    }
                }

Comment: This code returning false for above mentioned xml at node *trajectoryStation* even it has two child nodes : *dTimStn* and *typeTrajStation*

Comment: Then I seriously doubt that cNode points to the *trajectoryStation* element.

Comment: If possible can you please check out xml with the code which I send to you and solve how to get trajectoryStation child elements?..As of my observation, I think there is a problem with the xml